# FileObserver as continuous service

Tags: android, service, fileobserver

I want to implement a **FileObserver** to write a log whenever a certain file is changed. This should run **anytime** between boot and shutdown. After starting it no activity has to access it again.

I wrote a `Service` holding the instance of my `FileObserver`. But onEvent() only fires once and my service does not appear in `adb shell service list` at all.

Is this the wrong way to implement an ongoing background service?

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static FileObserver fileObserver;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

File file = new File("path/to/file");

    if (file.canRead()) {

        fileObserver = new FileObserver(file.getAbsolutePath(), FileObserver.MODIFY) {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {
                Log.i("FileObserver", "File modified!");
            }
        };

        fileObserver.startWatching();

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a foreground service which will keep running even you application is not in foreground. See the below example:

http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/

You can also try sticky service. This will make sure that your service is restarted when killed by Android.
Check the below link.
https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/creating-a-sticky-service-long-running-background-tasks.27065/

Comment: It seems to me that startForeground() only affects the notification. But I dont need any notification...

Comment: Well, in that case try the sticky service.